# Not reading value from dropdown list

Tags: forms, yii, model, html-select

'Duration' is a column in the table, which is 'required'

form:

```
<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'duration'); ?>

      <?php
           echo "<select>";
           echo "<option value=\"1\">1</option>";
           echo "<option value=\"1.5\">1.5</option>";
           echo "<option value=\"2\">2</option>";
           echo "<option value=\"2.5\">2.5</option>";
           echo "<option value=\"3\">3</option>";



      echo "</select>";
  ?>

    <?php echo $form->error($model,'duration'); ?>
</div>
```

When i choose an option it comes with the error 'Duration cannot be blank'. How to make it read the value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the name of the select is of `Model[duration]`

You need to have:

```
echo '<select name="ModelName[duration]">';
```

Also please don't mix PHP vanilla code in the Yii views, and use the methods provided by Yii.

I would do something like this:

```
echo CHtml::dropDownList('duration', $model, array('0' => 'Private', '1' => 'Public'));
```

Or even better:

```
echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'placement', $model::$def_duration, array('prompt' => 'Select'));
```

where `def_duration` would be a key=>value array defined in your model.

Comment: there should be nothing wrong with mixing "PHP vanilla code" with Yii views. A developer should have the option of doing this, and a framework should be flexible enough to handle this. Of course, the cost of a hybrid approach will be the loss of some of the benefits of using a full Yii approach. Don't mean to start a debate, just saying.